# What are the keys needed for a dictionary to create a UIPrintInfo object in Swift?

Tags: swift, printing, ios8.1

I am trying to print in Swift. I have watched the 2014 WWDC Adopting AirPrint video which makes it quite simple in Obj-C but I would really like to make this work in Swift. The documentation indicates that you have to create the UIPrintInfo object with a dictionary. That's fine, but how do you create the dictionary that UIPrintInfo needs? Specifically, what keys do you use? I have looked at the documentation, but it is not clear to me as to what the keys need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use a dictionary to create the `UIPrintInfo` instance, but the constants that would make this easy seem to be missing. Easier is to create an object with a `nil` dictionary and then set the properties. You can retrieve and inspect the dictionary representation once that's done.

```
let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
printInfo.printerID = savedPrinterID
printInfo.jobName = "My Print Job"
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplex.ShortEdge
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.Landscape
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.Photo

if let infoDict = printInfo.dictionaryRepresentation() {
    println(infoDict)
    // [UIPrintInfoOrientationKey: 1, UIPrintInfoJobNameKey: My Print Job,
    // UIPrintInfoPrinterIDKey: ABC123, UIPrintInfoOutputTypeKey: 1, 
    // UIPrintInfoDuplexKey: 2]
    let anotherPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: infoDict)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nate. I appreciate the help. While you were answering, I was also answering my own question. We got to the same point, just in a little different way. I had not thought about passing in nil for the dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, it's strange that you can't just initialize with `UIPrintInfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it, I found the answer by creating an Obj-C project, creating the UIPrintInfo object as the example project does, and then calling dictionaryRepresentation on the UIPrintInfo object (which returns the dictionary we need).

```
UIPrintInfo *printInfo=[UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType=UIPrintInfoOutputGrayscale;
printInfo.jobName=@"Print Job 1";
printInfo.orientation=UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;
printInfo.printerID=@"Printer ID Here";
NSDictionary *dict=[printInfo dictionaryRepresentation];
```

So here are the keys:

UIPrintInfoDuplexKey

UIPrintInfoOrientationKey

UIPrintInfoOutputTypeKey

UIPrintInfoPrinterIDKey

UIPrintInfoJobNameKey

The first three keys have int values from the enumerations listed in the documentation. The last two keys have string values of your own choosing.

Hope this helps someone else out.